# What values of $c$ will the sequence converge...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Determine what values of $c\in (0,\infty)$ the sequence defined by $a_n := \ln{(c)}^n$ is convergent.

Just looking for a place to start do we have to show $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = 0$?

Thanks.

Comment: Choose c such that |ln(c)|<1.

Comment: The expression you wrote is ambiguous, so it's not clear what the question is: is it $a_n=\ln(c^n)$ or $a_n=(\ln c)^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n$$ is converge when $r\in\left(-1, 1\right]$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n = 0$$ when $r\in\left(-1,1\right)$

---

So, $-1<\ln c\leq1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{e}<c\leq e$.

Comment: Why does it include $e$ but not $\frac{1}{e}$?

Comment: @squenshl take $c=e$ then $\ln c = 1$.
Then $a_n = 1^n = \left\{1, 1, 1, \cdots \right\}$. So $a_n$ converges to $1$.

take $c=\frac{1}{e}$ then $\ln c = -1$.
$a_n = (-1)^n = \left\{1, -1, 1, -1, \cdots\right\}$ and this is not converge.

Answer (score 0):

As you've written it, your sequence is equivalently defined by $n\log c,$ whence it becomes clear that no value of $c$ except $c=1$ ensures convergence of your series.